# Select New DOM elements created by Angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angularjs for a web application. I have tried searching to find a solution to my problem, and it seems that Angularjs do not facilitate an easy way to access newly created DOM elements within ng-Repeat.

I have prepared a jsfiddle to show the actual problem.
here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/956/

Please let me know how to select the new DOM element within ng-repeat.

Comment: Regarding dom manipulation in the controller, it [says here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/u52B5bVzdqs) that you should not do it at all. It should go in a directive. Why it doesn't work, I don't know, but it's probably because angular is still running its own stuff at this point in time.

Comment: I guess you will be able to get a better solution if you can explain why or for what reason you are trying to access the new dom element.  If you can explain that you will probably get an answer to solve your problem the angular way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment, I have updated your fiddle to show a simple implentation of a directive that alerts the class of the element.

http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/994/

Original comment:

Regarding dom manipulation in the controller, it [says here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/u52B5bVzdqs) that you should not do it at all. It should go in a directive. The controller should only contain business logic.

Why it doesn't work, I don't know, but it's probably because angular is still running its own stuff at this point in time.

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this:

**1 ng-init**

```
function controller($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{id: 1, name: 'one'}, {id: 2, name: 'two'}];

  $scope.initRepeaterItem(index, item) {
    console.log('new repeater item at index '+index+':', item);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-init="initRepeaterItem($index, item)"></li>
</ul>
```

**2 MutationObserver** *slightly more complex* 
Do this inside a directive, on the element whose parent gets new children (`<ul>` in this case)

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    // you get notified about DOM mutations here
    // check mutation.type if it was an insertion
    console.log(mutation.target.nodeName, mutation.type, mutation);
  });
});

var config = {childList: true, attributes: false, characterData: false, 
  subtree: false, attributeOldValue: false, characterDataOldValue: false};

observer.observe(element[0], config);
```

```
Demo              http://plnkr.co/h6kTtq
Documentation     https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver
Browser support   http://caniuse.com/mutationobserver
```